A way to assign a variable an attribute based on an element's value in CSS?
I want a margin-left of a div, .div1 equal to a padding-left of another div, .div2, I know you could just set the value of a variable and use it for corresponding attributes of both divs, but I need it to be dynamic.
.div1{
    margin-left:1.8%;
}
:root{
    --gappercent:/*.div1's margin-left value*/;
}
.div2{
    padding-left: var(--gappercent) /* OR .div1's margin-left value*/;
}

I'd like variable (--gappercent) to get assigned with the value of div1's left margin
For more Context:
My problem actually comes from woocommerce product container, specifically the add to cart button li.product .button and the quick view button .envo_shop_pro_preview from envo shop pro. Ive set .envo_shop_pro_preview to visible to support mobile view because it can only comes visible upon hover. Ive also set .envo_shop_pro_preview to position it beside li.product .button to make it easier to tap, here is the problem; li.product .button appears to have a margin (but it is actually from the padding of the li.product), and i want to get the value of the padding of li.product and give assign it as the value of .envo_shop_pro_preview's margin
.envo_shop_pro_preview{
    visibility:visible;
    position:absolute;
    length:20%;
    right:0;
}
li.product .button{
    length:80%;
}
li.product{
    padding:1.2% 1.8%; /*1.8% being the padding I want to get assigned to the margin of quick view*/
}

which I want to be:
.envo_shop_pro_preview{
    margin-right:/*li.product's padding-left/right*/;
}


Not possible with CSS except as you have already done with a variable. CSS can't detect an element's style only that it's an element and it's relation to other elements in the DOM.

give more context and what you want to achieve. I am pretty sure you want something that can be done differently

@TemaniAfif I've provided more context. I've actually found another way(unfortunately compromising margin of the li.product), I just wanted to know if something like the above question exists which I could generally use for css.
